# working from .txt file to output sha256 hashes in Python

Tags: python, hash

I have created a text file of randomly generated words, now i would like to write a script that can use that data to create sha256 hashes from those words...would prefer for hashes to be saved as a .txt file also, but in my failed attempt here I was simply trying to print them out. Any suggestions?

```
#!usr/bin/python
# Filename: doesnt_work

import os
import hashlib

with open("wordlist.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip("\n")

        m = sha256(line)
    print(m.hexdigest())
```

Comment: You should *always* post the exception you're getting. No one is psychic here.

Comment: Sorry, excellent point! ..first time asking question. I'm getting a return of one hash (ca978112ca1bbdcafac231b39a23dc4da786eff8147c4e72b9807785afee48bb) which isnt even the correct sha256 hash of the first word. Thanks.

Comment: You're getting that After following my answer below? Please post at least few lines of the wordlist file and the hashes you're getting.

Comment: Ahhhhh...cant separate them in this box...heres another try...separating with ####:  Kw)9Z,h4<|%#V####3F^B@0A]/foSV.T#### a:6c.'7####RNITKp"^\1xw####f$Lq^.kJjB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you should have posted the exception, I'm guessing this would fix it

```
 m = hashlib.sha256(line)
```

And there is an indentation problem

```
#!usr/bin/python
# Filename: doesnt_work

import os
import hashlib

with open("wl.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.rstrip("\n")

        m = hashlib.sha256(line)
        print(m.hexdigest())
```

Comment: Thanks for your help...O.K....originally it was giving me 1 hash that wasnt even correct for first word in the .txt file. (10 words in file while i work this out..) added your suggestion and now it skips a line in the python shell but no output.

Comment: You need to read `f` in some way. Try `for line in f.readlines()` instead.

Comment: @user3157868 make sure that @Bibhas's code is actually opening the right file. In your question you did `open("wordlist.txt")` and in Bibhas's answer he does `open('wl.txt')`

Comment: O.K...progress! I entered your suggestion of f.readkines(): ...added colon for syntax... Now I get error "m = hashlib.sha256(line)
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing   I'll work on it too and check for your suggestions. THANKS

Comment: O.K....made the following change : m = hashlib.sha256((line).encode('utf-8'))  ... it is now giving me the correct hash for the last word in the .txt file instead of all 5 words

Comment: GREAT! Thank you guys for all your help, and for being pretty easy on me for being new! All of your advice and my research yielded to following working script: #!usr/bin/python
# Filename: encryptiontest

import os
import hashlib

with open("wl.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        
        m = hashlib.sha256((line).encode('utf-8'))
        print(m.hexdigest())